# What is the correct way of reading strings in C to prevent problems

Tags: c, string, input, c-strings

I already searched about this, but I really could not find any answer that satisfied me. So, my doubt is related to string input in C when the string is a complete typed line in console. Until now, I was used to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int bar;
    char foo[30];

    scanf( "%d", &bar );

    fflush( stdin ); // prevent buffer "issue"
    gets( foo );
    fflush( stdin ); // I usually put this here too,
                     // but in most of times it is not
                     // necessary

    printf( "%d\n", bar );
    printf( "%s\n", foo );

    return 0;

}
```

But reading this [C++ Reference (gets)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/?kw=gets), I realized that the `gets` function is now removed from C spec (2011). So I search for another form to do the same thing and I found here in SO a post (I don't remember the link, sorry) that a way to do this is to use the `fgets` function. So, my code would be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int bar;
    char foo[30];

    scanf( "%d", &bar );

    fflush( stdin );
    fgets( foo, sizeof foo, stdin );
    fflush( stdin );

    printf( "%d\n", bar );
    printf( "%s test\n", foo );

    return 0;

}
```

It works fine, inteady by one detail. The `fgets` function reads the new line char too, and I don't want this. Lets suppose, if I input this sentence "one two", the first version of the program will store this in the c-string:

`'o'` | `'n'` | `'e'` | `' '` | `'t'` | `'w'` | `'o'` | `'\0'`

But the second version will store this:

`'o'` | `'n'` | `'e'` | `' '` | `'t'` | `'w'` | `'o'` | `'\n'` | `'\0'`

And I don't want this, because one of the problems might be string comparision, since I will need to compare strings with the new line char too, and this would be a problem, for example, between windows and linux, since they use different patterns for new line (\r\n and \n repectivelly).

So, my question is: How can I read a c-string using just a standard function?
My doubt arises because I'm teacher at a federal institute here in Brazil and I work with introductory programming disciplines and I would like something simple that works fine, but some disciplines use C as programming language. Of course, a way is to replace the new line char, but I can't do this! I need a simple line that do the work, without idiomatic constructs. I work with extremamly "low level" students...

Comment: For text streams, C guarantees that a newline is always `\n`, regardless of the operating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior, don't do it.

---

Otherwise, the solution is trivial: after `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)`, replace the newline characters with a 0-terminator:

```
char *p;

p = strchr(buf, '\r');
if (p) *p = 0;

p = strchr(buf, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, but I would like something simpler. I'm teacher and I teach some introdutory programmimg classes and one of them uses C as programming language, so I would like something simple to teach, at least on the start of the course. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: @davidbuzatto This is simple. **This is very simple.**

Comment: No, it is not, at least for my needs... Sorry. You can't even think the level of the most of my students...

Comment: @davidbuzatto I assure you I can. There are people [like this](http://icanhaztehcodez.tumblr.com) on Stack Overflow. They shouldn't even touch the computer, let alone try "programming"...

Comment: @davidbuzatto By the way, if you are using C and not C++, don't refer cplusplus.com. C and C++ are two very distinct languages, and anyway, cplusplus.com is a very low-quality site, it contains a lot of mistakes. Cite the man pages of The Open Group when using C, and use en.cppreference.com if you need C++ documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would follow your recomendations about the documentations. I thought that reading the "c" libraries in cplusplus.com was correct. I will bookmark these docs. Thanks again!

Comment: @davidbuzatto: And don't forget to check the *return value* of `fgets()`. It returns NULL if nothing was read at all (and the buffer need not contain a valid string in that case).

Comment: :MartinR I know this detail, but thanks for your complement ;)

Comment: @P0W I told you :) (And these people are trying to write programs without having any common sense at all! I could cry sometimes...)

Comment: :H2CO3, you saind that fflush have undefined behavior, but how can I manage the problem with my code (use scanf before reading a string). Try my code without the fflush calls (the first one to be exactly). The string input will not work...

Comment: @davidbuzatto What do you mean exactly? You can't `fflush(stdin);`. Also, what's all with `scanf()`? Again, don't use it, use `fgets()` throughout the code.

Comment: @H2CO3: the problem is when you use scanf before fgets (and so gets), it seems that the new line char of the previous input (scanf) is not processed, so it remains in the buffer. When fgets is called, the buffer is processed and since there is a remaining `\n` in it, fgets process it and the impression is that the function does not work, since the program will not stop to wait for the new input.

Comment: @davidbuzatto That's why you **don't use** `scanf()` at all, but you use `fgets()` and `strtol()` to read an integer, and you always check the return value of `fgets()`.

Comment: @H2CO3: Ok, understood! The same way I do in Java, i.e., not mixing nextInt(), nextDouble(), etc. with nextLine() method calls of Scanner class.

Comment: @davidbuzatto If you wish so, then yes!

Comment: @davidbuzatto  You could use `getchar();` so that it will eat up the newline . There are so many posts around here regarding this .

Comment: Sorry ,I make a mistake

Comment: @davidbuzatto that it is not only effective in the treatment of a particular system is `fflush(stdin)` is a problem. Teachers should not teach such a thing.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: My students, as I, will not use C to program system, not anything big. We use C just to work with algorithms.

Comment: @davidbuzatto: Interactive I/O in C can either be simple (`scanf`) or robust (`fgets` + handling newlines + converting numeric values + ...); you can't have both at the same time.  That's just the nature of the language.

Comment: @davidbuzatto If you want simpler why not use the commandline arguments to get input into your C programs rather than doing interactive I/O from within your C program. Most shell environments have decent interactive i/o already

Comment: This answer is good, but what is the purpose of looking for `\r`. In text streams, a newline is always `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way is to read via `fgets`

```
char line[BUFSIZ] = "";

while (line = fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    size_t len = strlen(line); 
    /* Remove newline */ 
    if (line[len - 1] == '\n') {
        line[len - 1] = '\0'; 
    } 
    /* process line */
}
```